# getting numbers from a string c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have an input string like below:

```
"/myWS/api/Application/IsCarAvailable/123456/2017"
```

It is the end of a Web API call that I am making.  I need to easily extract the 123456 from the URL.

I was hoping something like the below would work

```
       string[] numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");
```

However, when I set a breakpoint on numbers and run the code it is showing an array of 3 elements?

```
Element at [0] is ""
Element at [1] is 123456
Element at [2] is 2017
```

Does anyone see why it would be getting the empty string as the first element?

Comment: Do you just need this part of the string `"/123456/"`?

Comment: Not sure about the regular expression, but if the format is guaranteed to be as displayed you might consider `String.Split` and just look at the last two elements.

Comment: Try this `\w+(?=\d\/)\w`.

Comment: `string[] numbers = Regex.Replace(input, @"\D+", " ").Trim(' ').Split(' ');` got locked before I could post answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest *matching*, not *splitting*:

```
   string source = @"/myWS/api/Application/IsCarAvailable/123456/2017";

   string[] numbers = Regex 
     .Matches(source, "[0-9]+") 
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(match => match.Value)
     .ToArray();
```

Please, notice that `\d+` in .Net means *any* unicode digits (e.g. *Persian* ones: `۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹`): that's why I put `[0-9]+` pattern (`RegexOptions.ECMAScript` is an alternative if `\d+` pattern is preferrable).

Comment: can you give a quick comment on the difference in matching and splitting?

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat: matching: is extracting `[0-9]+` (2 items); splitting: using `\D+` delimiter split existing string: `[\D+]123456[\D+]2017` and you have **3** items: *empty*, `123456`, `2017`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Upvoting Dmitry's answer since he was faster than me and more precise in reasoning :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your string is always in the same format, this would work:

```
string numbers = input.Split('/')[input.Split('/').Length - 2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the split method "splits" the string at the matching expression. So the empty string is the part before the first match.
Any reason why you would not use `Regex.Matches(input,"\\d+")` instead?

```
        string numtest = "http://www.google.com/test/123456/7890";
        var matchResult = Regex.Matches(numtest, "\\d+");
        for (int i = 0; i < matchResult.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine($"Element {i} is {matchResult[i].Value}");
```

Hope that helps. Regards!